# Is the only way to use 'params' in a controller action to give it an array from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a method within a controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetPreference(params string[] settings)
{
    // Do things related to getting preferences
    return Json(preferencesList);
}
```

Is the only means to pass parameters to this method from an AJAX call an array? Are there any more graceful or elegant methods?

```
$.get(url, { settings: [color, rotation] });
```

Comment: You can declare and initialize the array up front so you can do this.
 
$.get(url, { settings: arrayvar });

Comment: Good question and one that should be explored a bit more.  MVC as it turns out converts Get and Post requests from the Query String data of the HTTP Get or Post, JSON always uses name value pairs so the stage is set for allowing MVC to convert the query string or JSON name value pairs to strong types.  Here's how MVC converts strong types on POSTS, the post is sent with the query string to the proper controller.  MVC then parses the name value pairs and injects them into the strong type signature of the controller.  As long as there are name matches you get everything as a strong type.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should be able to do something along the lines of this:

```
GET /SomeController/GetPreference?settings%5B0%5D=first&settings%5B1%5D=second
```

(where `%5B` is `[` and `%5D` is `]`) or even just

```
GET /SomeController/GetPreference?settings=first&settings=second
```

See [this post by Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) and [this one by Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/).

The former is useful if you want to use complex types rather than just `string` or `int`.